# Get Item Id from name Arabic WordNet

Tags: java, arabic, semantics, wordnet

I need to use Arabic WordNet (AWN) in my project, but there are some vague concepts or words within:
What is the difference between Item,Word,Form ?

Also,I have called an Java API function that take an Arabic term an return Item_Id (I think Item_Id is the Id for the term, so it should return just one Id), but it returns more than one! like following:

Code:

```
List<String> ItemID = awn.Get_Item_Id_From_Name("قتل");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ItemID.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println( ItemID.get(i) );
    }
```

OutPut:

> qatala_v5AR
>
> qatala_v6AR
>
> qatala_v1AR
>
> qatala_v2AR
>
> qatala_v3AR
>
> qatala_v4AR
>
> qatol_n1AR
>
> qatol_n2AR
>
> qatol_n3AR
>
> qatol_n4AR

What they are?